# How to use wkhtmltopdf and Azure Functions together to convert HTML to IMAGE?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I have an AF to which I pass a parameter with a website and the function creates a blob with a converted html to image. How exactly to do this with wkhtmltopdf, as I understand that some .exe needs to be uploaded somewhere near my Azure Function, but do not fully understand the whole procedure. I downloaded the wkhtmltopdf installer from the website and then installed it on my Windows machine. What do I need to do on Azure? Any tutorials or lessons?

I am using this: https://github.com/mrdaghestani/HtmlPI
but do not understand this part:

> First you have to install wkhtmltopdf on application server (your developing system or client's systems)

How to install this on Azure so my Azure Function to work there?

```
[FunctionName("htmlToImage")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = 
null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
string url = req.Query["url"];

byte[] EncodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(url);
string DecodedURL = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(EncodedData);

string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
DecodedURL = DecodedURL ?? data?.name;

HtmlConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlConverter();
var filePath = htmlConverter.Convert(new GenerateSettings { Url = DecodedURL, OutputType = OutputType.Image });

//string BlobName = "myblob1";
//string ImageURL = await CreateBlob($"{BlobName}.png", (byte[])..., log);

var Result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

//
// JSON
//
var oJSON = new { url = ImageURL, hash = BlobName };
var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oJSON);

Result.Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn);
Result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

return Result;
}
```

Comment: May be you can follow something similar to this. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/

Comment: I'm attempting to do something similar now, did you ever resolve your issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Function app's file system via [Kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/05/15/using-kudu-and-deploying-apps-into-azure/), which you can access via https://{your function app name}.scm.azurewebsites.net, then selecting Debug Console > CMD or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of caveats while using wkhtmltopdf on Azure Functions.

- You need atleast a Basic (B1) Plan to run executable files.
- Secondly, Only 32 bits wkhtmltopdf is supported on Windows so you need to switch your functions to 32 bits.
- As Katy mentioned you need to access the system via Kudu and upload your either libwkhtmltox.dll (Windows) or libwkhtmltox.dll.so (Linux) files to the root folder of the site based on the OS.

I would suggest that you go ahead with a Linux Basic plan since it is cheaper compared to Windows Basic plan.

You can find a comprehensive blog on how to setup wkhtmltopdf for Azure Functions [here](https://arjavdave.com/2021/03/22/azure-functions-wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: since the last update of dinktopdf is 5 years ago, any idea on how to get the latest compiled wkhtmltopdf libraries that can be used with dink2pdf ?